# Testing REST API with MOCKITO

Tags: spring

I have a problem with testing the REST API using MOCKITO

I have an example of the rest controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/workers")
public class WorkOfferController {

@Autowired
private  WorkerService workerService;

@PostMapping(value = "/lists", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity searchWorker(@RequestBody RecruitmentSearchRequest recruitmentSearchRequest, @RequestParam("page") int page,  @RequestParam("size") int size,) throws NoSuchFieldException {
System.err.print('WorkerController');
        return workerService.getWorkers(recruitmentSearchRequest, page, size);
}
```

}

And the right service for it:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class WorkerService {
private final WorkerRepistory workerRepository;
private final UserRepository userRepository;

public ResponseEntity getWorkers(RecruitmentSearchRequest recruitmentSearchRequest,int pageNumber, int size) throws NoSuchFieldException {
System.err.print('WorkerService');
...
}
```

}

I want to test whether everything is okay under the url with the right data. I do not want to use this database because I prefer Mockito.

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @SpringBootTest(classes = Appp2workApplication.class)
    @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
    public class PharmacyWorkOfferRestDocsTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private WorkOfferController workOfferController;

    @Mock
    private WorkerService workerService;
@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

@Mock
WorkerRepistory workerRepository;




@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(workOfferController).build();
}

@Test
public void searchWorkOfferListWithParameters() throws Exception {
    String payload = "{\n" +
            "\t\"name\":\"tomek\",\n" +
            "\t\"searchFromSalary\":5,\n" +
            "}";

    Mockito.doNothing().when(userRepository.save(Mockito.anyObject()));
    Mockito.when(searchService.getRecruitmentOfferJobListWithParameters(Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(list);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/workers/lists?page=0&size=20").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(payload))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

}

And I have a problem that with this approach the test comes to me in the controller and displays "WorkerController" but I do not want to enter the service from this controller, and it returns 200, but it really only came to the controller and that's it. This is probably because WorkerService is as Mock but I tried to give it as eg Autowired or InjectMock and it is still the same.
What do I do wrong that I enter into the controller but I do not want to use this controller for the appropriate service?